# Is this a bad pattern for reporting/audit?

Tags: design, design-patterns, enterprise-architecture, workflows, reporting

We have a large code base with lots of workflow data (camunda) that does this:

- Create a reporting event in the codebase
- Give it a code + payload
- Put the item on a message queue
- Consume queue elsewhere using lambdas
- Write data to the warehouse

Whenever the workflow changes, new reporting events are written.
Start/End times for events are hard to track, requires downstream reporting changes for new codes, and reporting events are frequently missing due to restarts.

The users are not happy. Is there a better pattern I'm missing?
What I'm considering is using Camunda API polling to track events and using reverse ETL instead on the DBs.

Comment: is the problem making these audit event work with a camunda workflow which can be restarted or edited mid process?

Comment: I just watched the camunda video, surely by 2023 we have got wise to the "any user can just drag and drop draw new process! you don't need programmers!" scam

Comment: You might want to clarify: what is "the warehouse" for, why "start/End times for events are hard to track", why there are "restarts", why would a different synchronization pattern solve all these problems? The current question is pretty obscure - unless it's written in some secret Camunda slang I don't get.

Comment: Sure. Start/End times are when events start/finish with an associated duration. Restarts are when the applications are redeployed.
No secret camunda sauce, just a bunch of data which needs to be emitted which is slowing us down.

Answer (score 1):

The steps you listed in your question are a high level description of a standard solutions. It is too high level though, there are a lot of details of the implementation that are not trivial. First of all  all the data in the payload of the event should be labelled and searchable. The search tool also matters, often to speed up the performance the tools skips unindexed data, but in this way a lot of events often go missing.

One example. In my experience often when a transaction spans multiple system each one generates its own transaction ID. Often events contain both the transaction ID of the called and calling service. When a third service is called it might report only one of the two previous IDs adding a third. Then the administrator trying to reconstruct the transaction starting from one transaction ID has to retrieve the others in order to gather all the events.

If the payload is not taken into account and the warehouse is searched only by event code I am not surprised that the systems often is not able to reconstruct the transactions. That is error prone. But If the implementation has problems it does not mean it is a bad pattern. Depending on how the payload is done, how the warehouse works and few other details the system you described could be adjusted. Maybe starting from the search tool.

If there are so many problems that the entire system is difficult to fix and you want to make the case with your colleagues to replace it completely I think you would need to write down a lot more details.  Just calling it a bad pattern would sound too vague and referring to the high level solution as a bad pattern would not be even correct.

Comment: Bounded context in DDD is part of the problem. Seems like we developed a blended SOA/EDM with the EDM part being a 2nd class citizen. The domains output their own reporting events but don't necessarily care that much about correctness.
Difficult for us to change at least. Can't really see a way forward unless there is a major refactor investment.
In hindsight, standard ETL was probably a better option in this case. Leave the domains to their own devices!

Comment: Even if the implementation is problematic I would not define the steps listed in the question an anti-pattern. Let's not abuse the  term.

Comment: @DocBrown You're right. I fixed my post.

Answer (score 1):

> Put the item on a message queue
> ...
> reporting events are frequently missing due to restarts

Restart of what ?

The message queue restarts:
Surely you should be using a message queue service (plenty of such tools out there) that persists the messages and does not loose them across restarts. Unless you are also developing the message queue and frequently deploy it.

The product software restarts:
Well if a message made it to the queue, and the messaging service is of the above mentioned quality, no message should get lost unless things are down for really large spans of time.

> Start/End times for events are hard to track, requires downstream reporting changes for new codes

One convention is of using hierarchical "ancestor" IDs for reporting messages.

```
(event) -> Message(id:123, payload:...)
   |
   |---(event) -> Message(id:456, from:[123], payload:...)
          |
          |----(event) -> Message(id:789, from:[123,456], payload:...)
```

The events generated usually have ID(s) of the parent transaction(s), request(s) or scope(s). From the starting event, you can query the last event in hierarchy and obtain time spans as well, without bothering about the codes.

Comment: Application restarts. As reporting is not as important as the actual transaction, we often lose the reporting events on redeployment.